# Should I wait to buy Resharper until VS 2010 is released?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

I have used up my 30 day trial and want to buy Resharper now.  But, I'm poor and $150 is a lot for me to handle right now.

Is anything in VS 2010 going to make buying Resharper now a mistake?  I heard that VS 2010 is like VS 2008 + Resharper.

I find it hard to believe but wanted to ask SO before spending my money.

Thanks!

Result:  I bought Resharper and have not regretted it since.  I use it's code navigation and refactoring tools many times throughout the day. I seriously cannot use VS2008 without it.

Comment: For those who come here: This question is no longer relevant. JetBrains now offers a free upgrade to Resharper 5.0 for new purchases, which supports Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all look at the prospects of R# 4.5 to know what will be included in it: http://resharper.blogspot.com/2008/07/whats-next-life-after-release.html and http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/19/resharper-45.html
I'm sure that R# will be must-have add-in for VS2010 too (JetBrains spent several years working on it and it will be hard for MS to do a really good implementation of all these features). And also you may check R# 4.5 nightly builds and compare'em with betas of VS.

Answer (score 4):

From the VS previews I have seen so far, there are some enhancements to 2010 that overlap with today's Resharper, but I'm sure the next version of Resharper will in turn add even more to fill in new gaps that VS leaves out. It's an ever-forward march.

That doesn't really answer your question directly, but hopefully the extra info will help you decide.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of [this](http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2009/01/19/visual-studio-2010-visual-studio-2008-resharper.aspx).. I held off springing for Resharper for a while, but I haven't regretted it since I did.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how anyone can stand VS without ReSharper.  Beg, borrow or steal the money for a copy!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, Resharper had a good upgrade policy between 3.x and 4.x.  If you bought 3.x near the end of their cycle, you got a free upgrade to 4.x.  IIRC, that gap was more than a couple months, so it was pretty nice.  If they do something like that, you might benefit lots by buying early.  Resharper is great, and I get a little angry now when I have to use a VS installation that doesn't have it!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of functionality in VS2010, Resharper is worth every penny of that $150 right now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for slightly over the $150 asking price I can obtain an entire operating system.  Don't you all think this is a bit steep?  Practically once a year I am asked to fork out another couple hundred to buy the upgrades.  So, I ask you, what is better in 4.1 versus 3.0 version.  I have 3.0 and have installed the 4.1 trial and did not see $150 worth of improvements.  It may crash less, but the added functionality is not worth another $150.  I uninstalled and put my 3.0 back.  It works fine for now.  Maybe the 4.5 version might have something new to make it worth the big bucks.

Comment: Honestly, if you use resharper to its full extent and write code for a living, you can easily make up the 150 bucks in increased productivity.  It's was just that much better than the built-in VS2005 capabilities.

Comment: Agreed.  It's worth every penny.

Comment: Prices are relative. MS sells a ton more of Windows than Jetbrains selling R#. Comparison is not valid. Before you pay for upgrades, test using the trial and make an informative decision.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure people said that VS2008 was like VS2005 + R#... I don't think that's true. Sure, VS 2005 introduced some refactoring support, but there was better support in R#, plus R# does tons more than just refactoring.

My advice, buy it now. It'll redeem it's $150 value in time and effort saved well before VS 2010 ships anyway (even if VS 2010 ships next week you'll still reap the benfits, IMHO).

As for the comments another poster made about the cost. I agree it's not cheap, but I 
think the ROI for me is about a week. In other words it's an investment worth making.

PS. If you like R# and use [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) I'd strongly recommend checking out the R# add-in called [StyleCop for R#](http://www.codeplex.com/StyleCopForReSharper)